# Плагиат коммерческого сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

В августе этого года я решил со своей девушкой запустить бизнес по продаже браслетов. Так как я сам являюсь программистом, я решил написать сайт. Мой дизайн был полностью уникальным, я на ходу придумывал расположение элементов, цвет кнопок и не раз их менял. В общем окончательный вид страницы был определен через месяц от начала разработки.

И вот, вчера я захожу в интернет, вбиваю в поиск гугл браслеты и обнаруживаю, что в интернете находится клон моего сайта. Практически 90% сайта скопировано. А когда я посмотрел исходный код страницы обнаружил что код тоже мой. Мне не понравилось, что человек (по сути мой конкурент) полностью скопировал мой сайт, поставив только свои браслеты (так как поставщик у него другой), и не спросил у меня разрешения. Запустил рекламу и успешно продает товар.

Еще месяц назад, меня странным образом заблокировал гугл адворс якобы за продажу реплик. Хотя в поисковиках рекламируется куча неоригинальных товаров. Так что у меня есть подозрения что это тоже был он. Так как обычно такие сайты блокируют если кто-то специально напишет жалобу. И вот таким черным образом он вытеснил меня и по сути украл мой бизнес. Еще ранее, несколько раз мне звонили недовольные клиенты, якобы я продал им плохой товар, хотя это были не мы. Теперь стало ясно, что они просто перепутали наши сайты. Я написал ему на почтовый ящик, но меня игнорируют.

Итак, вот в чем вопрос: какими инструментами можно доказать, что мой сайт был выложен в сеть раньше его. И можно ли подать в суд за нарушение авторских прав, по статье нарушения интеллектуальной собственности? Или можно максимум заставить хостинг/поисковик убрать сайт из индекса?

Ссылки на сайты:

- [Мой сайт](http://juststyle.in.ua/pandora)
- [Копия 1](http://pandorastyle.in.ua)
- [Копия 2](http://pandora.pascal.com.ua)

Comment: Вот также и Цукерберг наварился на идеях и кодах братьев Уинклвосс. Таков мир. Безжалостный и беспощадный ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Кто первый встал, того и тапки.

Comment: С Вашими аргументами в суд идти бесполезно. Суд будет разговаривать, когда есть юридически зафиксированные права на фирменный стиль. В данном случае можно только попробовать наказать подлеца (а оно Вам надо? Затравите эти сайты, откроет другой лохотрон).

Comment: Оставьте лучше просто "все права защищены, копирование материалов [прследуется по закону или аналог]" в подвале. Текущий вариант серьезности не прибавляет.

Comment: Может быть, убрать ссылки из вопроса? Иначе получается как бы реклама.

Comment: Предлагаю закрытие: юридические вопросы не относятся к темам, обсуждаемым на этом подсайте.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , тогда тапки мои, так как я первый запустил сайт)

Comment: @VladD, главным вопросом остается, как узнать какой сайт был запущен ранее, мой или их.

Comment: @Valentine Murnik я не говорил запустил, я написал - встал. То есть он крепко и быстро на ноги встал и протолкнул также быстро и эффективно так, что вы не удел, а все считают что тот сайт - оригинал.

Comment: А по-моему, полезный сообществу вопрос. А то получается так, что программисты ничерта не смыслят в юриспруденции, да и вообще, в реальной жизни, а потом мы жалуемся, что всем заправляют тупые говноменеджеры...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> можно ли подать в суд за нарушение авторских прав, по статье нарушения
>   интеллектуальной собственности

К сожалению, если у Вас нет договора на разработку фирменного стиля/кода, и/или если Вы не регистрировали права на фирменный стиль/код, обращаться в суд будет бесполезно, т.к. кроме слов Вам нечем подтвердить свои права на интеллектуальную собственность.

**UPD**

ради интереса поговорили с юристами и вот к чему приходим:

**Доказательства** - доказательствами является все, что Вы можете приложить для подтверждения авторских прав:

1. Договор на разработку - хороший плюс если Вы у кого-то заказали сайт(однако помним, что конкурент может задним числом сделать и себе договор)
2. Нотариальная регистрация права собственности на код/дизайн(лучшее подтверждение)
3. Ценное письмо со скриншотом кода, дизайна, отправленное самому себе в дни разработки(и лучше нераспакованное)
4. Выкладка на ином ресурсе исходника кода/дизайна
5. Исходники psd изображении и т.п.
6. Дата изменения файлов на сервере
7. Кеш поисковиков (весьма сомнительное док-во без официального подтверждения владельца поисковика).
8. Свидетели(совсем забыли про них), - люди, которые могут подтвердить, что Вы владелец сайта и фирменного стиля с какого-то числа или, что Ваш сайт с таким дизайном был запущен с какого-то числа.

Если у Вас есть что-то из вышеперечисленных доказательств, Вы можете обратиться в суд, однако если у Вас нет нотариально оформленных прав ситуация 50 на 50, все будет зависеть от умения юристов. Для Вас главное, чтобы у конкурент не смог доказать свои права или то, что он создал фирменный стиль/код раньше Вас.

**Запомните**, если Вы не докажите вину конкурента, он может подать на возмещение убытков, т.е. все что он потратит на суд и на юристов, оплатите Вы.

Comment: А какой-нибудь кэш поисковика, который покажет, что сайт был старше?

Comment: Ну, кеш гугла для суда и не является доказательством. Мало ли, может на одном сайте robots.txt неправильно прописан был. Гугл не истина в последней инстанции.

Comment: @VladD, как вариант, первый сайт есть в кеше за то время, когда ещё не тыл куплен второй домен - наверное, это уже нечто более доказательное?

Comment: @Qwertiy: На мой вкус, нет. Timestamp в кеше гугла не является для гугла юридически обязывающим.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вот если сотрудник гугла под присягой покажет, что он лично видел этот сайт такого-то числа — это пойдёт за свидетельские показания.

Comment: @VladD, кстати, у меня был консультант по рекламе в adwords он видел мой сайт ведь он помогал мне настроить рекламу.

Comment: @Alex, а если конкурент заплатит какому-то Васе, чтобы он назвался консультантом и его сайт был запущен раньше?

Comment: @Alex, слова консультанта можно подкрепить датой регистрации домена. У конкурента дата регистрации позже, чем у ТС.

Comment: @LEQADA регистрация домена еще не значит запуск сайта, наверняка к этому прицепятся юристы конкурента.

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант - написать регистратору и хостеру притензию. Если грамотно юридически составите - легко могут заблокировать сайт вашего конкурента без вопросов. Тут многое зависит от самого хостера и вашего правильно составленного письма.
Плюс можете написать злоумышленнику по его адресу письмо или позвонить по номеру на их сайте и поговорить лично. Вариантов то много и без суда)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы предлагаете пойти на противоправные действия?

Comment: VladD, Процитируйте пожалуйста текст из моего сообщения, который нарушает закон. Все в рамках прав.

Comment: @Dofri, в вашей стране DDoS считается правомерным?

Comment: Например, «Примерное содержание такое - а-ля написал в отдел К заявление на ваши неправомерные использование чужого кода. Все штрафы после заведения дела будете выплачивать в соответствии с законом.» — явный шантаж.

Comment: По поводу ддоса - соглашусь, возможно это перебор. Но если бы у меня так нагло украли сайт - я бы рассмотрел все варианты. Чтобы не плодить дискуссии - отредактировал свой стартовый пост.

Comment: @Dofri: Закон совершенно однозначно говорит, что вы не можете нарушать закон даже в ответ на нарушение закона другим. «Рассмотрел все варианты» выглядит не очень красиво.

Comment: еще раз повторюсь, что не собираюсь начинать тут юридические споры, если они вам интересны, можем пообщаться в личке - не стоит засорять тему. Пост я уже поправил, дабы вас не смущать.

Comment: @Dofri сайт не заблокируют без решения суда или если Вы не предъявите прав на код/фирменный стиль (в последнее мало верится).

Comment: Alex, а вот тут вы не правы. Лично знаю как минимум 2 случая, когда хостер блокировал сайт просто после письменного обращения от правообладателя, подкрепленного здравыми и логичными аргументами. Все очень сильно зависит от хостера.

Comment: @Dofri мы говорим о том, что у человека нет договора и он не регистрировал права, что он может предъявить хостеру? *Не исключено, что есть хостеры о которых Вы говорите, но их мало, т.к. никто из своего кармана не хочет платить, также как и потерять клиента.* Если Вас не затруднит, напишите пожалуйста, какие хостеры блокировали сайты по письму, может быть пригодится кому-нибудь когда-нибудь.

Answer (score 2):

Обращаться в поисковики бесполезно, если ваша фамилия не Цукерберг, у вас надежда только на автоматические алгоритмы. С их точки зрения "кто первый встал, того и тапки", но есть нюансы: нужно, чтобы и у оригинала, и у копии было достаточно текстового контента (чтобы у автоматики были основания для выводов), контент совпадал (для признания копией), и ваш сайт ранжировался заметно выше (это значит больше входящих качественных ссылок). В этом случае конкурент пропадает из выдачи поисковика как "копия".

На дизайн поисковикам наплевать. Вообще, если что-то надизайнили, и у вас получилось неплохо, смритесь с тем, что дизайн будут тырить. К слову, ваш конкурент неплохо доработал ваше оформление: картинка не растянута криво, шрифт нормально работает во всех браузерах. Правда картинку перерисовать поленился. Учитесь. ;-)

Ну а попытки зарабатывать на адвордс на сайте магазина, причём запрещённого по правилам — это вообще странная затея. Вы только распугаете покупателей, при этом ничего не заработав. Я уж молчу о том, что зарабатывать на нарушении правил — чревато.

Comment: да я как-бы back-end, а на то время не было средств на верстальщика. Сделал как умел) Клиентов было много и все довольны, так как знали что продаются реплики на сайте есть информация и по телефону каждый раз повторяем.

Comment: @ValentineMurnik Картинку хоть поправьте, а то квадратные головы выглядят страшно. Никогда не меняйте пропорции картинок. Ну и "защиту" от правого клика уберите, она никогда ни от чего не защищала.

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации, картинку поправлю)